# tikz picture in eso-pic

Tags: tikz-pgf, eso-pic

I construct a macro named `\drawline` to draw a picture by `tikz` package on every page(by `eso-pic` package).
When I call this macro twice in order to pain two lines in different places and with different color(red and blue), the typeset gives two lines with the same color(red - the color given in the last call).
Why and how to deal with this problem?
PS：In the following MWE, only one arg is given. In fact, there are several other args other than for tikz, so `\pgfkeys` must be used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic,xparse,picture}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\drawlinecenter}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtTextCenter{%
      \put(\xx,\yy){%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[center,line width=6pt]
          (0,0) -- (0,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }}}}
%    
\newcommand{\drawlineupperleft}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
      \put(\xx,\yy){%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[upperleft,line width=6pt]
          (0,0) -- (0,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }}}}
%      
% main macro:
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawline}{O{}m}{% #1-optional style arg. #2-position
  \tikzset{%
    x/.code=\def\xx{##1},x/.default=0pt,
    y/.code=\def\yy{##1},y/.default=0pt,
    #2/.style={x,y,#1}
  }
  \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,x,y,#1}
  \csname drawline#2\endcsname
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\drawline[color=blue,x=1cm]{center}
\drawline[color=red,x=10cm]{upperleft}
firstpage\clearpage second page\clearpage third page
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting the line color. I would probably just store these things in styles. Apart from solving the issue you will be more flexible, i.e. could add e.g. `dashed` and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic,xparse}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\drawlinecenter}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtTextCenter{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[center,line width=6pt]
          (0,0) -- (0,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }}}
%    
\newcommand{\drawlineupperleft}{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \AtTextUpperLeft{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[upperleft,line width=6pt]
          (0,0) -- (0,1);
      \end{tikzpicture}
    }}}
%      
% main macro:
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawline}{O{}m}{% #1-optional style arg. #2-position
  \tikzset{#2/.style={#1}}
  \csname drawline#2\endcsname
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\drawline[color=blue]{center}
\drawline[color=red]{upperleft}
firstpage\clearpage second page\clearpage third page
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @marmot. As I said, \pgfkeys has to be used because there are other non-tikz arguments. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @lyl `\tikzset` *is* using pgfkeys. The command `\tikzset{#2/.style={#1}}` is equivalent to `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,#2/.style={#1}}`.

Comment: I mean there are other arguments that are not used for environment of tikzpicture. For example, odd for odd pages, even for even pages. And all these args(related and not related to tikzpicture) should be in #1 by the form of key=value

Comment: I just understand what you mean, and this is a perfect solution. Still, why do optional args in \draw not expand, but args in style do?

Comment: @lyl You have one variable, `\linecolor`, which gets overwritten the way you set up the code. The proposal here is in a certain way equivalent to having a variable `\linecolorUpperLeft` and a variable `\linecolorCenter`. That is, there are two different styles with different names that cannot interfere with each other.

Comment: I modified my code in your proposal@marmot. Now a new problem, those args appeared before /.style are overwrited by the last call, as shown in my new code. I added two new args(x, y) to control the position of the lines. The blue lines shoud move only 1cm, but the typeset shows that it also move 10cm. Is there a way to deal with such a problem? Thank you.

Comment: @lyl This is the same problem as before, you overwrite `\xx` and `\yy`. Notice that you do not have to work with `\put`. Rather, you are already employing Ti*k*Z, so you can use absolute page coordinates if you add `[overlay,remember picture]` after `\begin{tikzpicture}`. Then you could make the shifts part of the style. I could add something along these lines, but it might be more efficient if I got the full picture before.

Comment: Is there any tircks to expand args which locate before /.style?

Comment: @lyl I am sorry, I do not understand your question. (You can expand args with `.../.expanded=...`, is that what you mean?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89216/discussion-between-lyl-and-marmot).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to marnot, the following may be a solution(in which `pgf's /.expanded` used):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,eso-pic,picture}

\begin{document}
% main macro:
\NewDocumentCommand{\drawline}{O{}m}{% #1-optional style arg. #2-position
  \pgfkeys{%
    x/.store in=\x,x/.default=0,
    y/.store in=\y,y/.default=0,
    color/.store in=\cl,color/.default=blue,
    tc/.code n args={3}{%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
          \AtTextCenter{%
             \put(##1,##2){%
               \tikz\draw[draw=##3,line width=6pt](0,0) -- (0,1);
            }}}},
    ul/.code n args={3}{%
        \AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
          \AtTextUpperLeft{%
            \put(##1,##2){%
              \tikz\draw[draw=##3,line width=6pt](0,0) -- (0,1);
            }}}},  
   }
   \pgfkeys{x,y,color,#1,#2/.expanded={\x}{\y}{\cl}}
 }
% test
\drawline[color=green,x=-5cm]{tc}
\drawline{tc}
\drawline[color=red,x=0cm,y=-3cm]{ul}

first page\clearpage second page\clearpage third page
\end{document}
```